# Hyper-V 2012 R2 Generations

Tags: hyper-v

Can anyone differentiate between generation 1 and generation 2 in details?

Just like a comparison to make to much more clear.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

From: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282285.aspx

> **Generation 1**   Provides the same virtual hardware to the virtual machine as in previous versions of Hyper-V.
>
> **Generation 2**   Provides the following new functionality on a virtual
>   machine:
>
> - PXE boot by using a standard network adapter
> - Boot from a SCSI virtual hard disk
> - Boot from a SCSI virtual DVD
> - Secure Boot (enabled by default)
> - UEFI firmware support
>
> IDE drives and legacy network adapter support has been removed

Additional information about each bullet is available in the linked technet article above.